# Monitoring files in folders

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, synchronization, directory

So my code works now by notifying me when files have not been added.
My Problem now is that I have more customers and my `foreach` loop does not seem to work. It still emails me 1 customer.

Here is my code:

```
[string]$path = "X:\Brievenbus\Customer1"
[string]$path = "X:\Brievenbus\Customer2"

 $File = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-1) }


$SMTPMessage = @{
To = $To
From = $From
Subject = "$Subject at $Path"
Smtpserver = $SMTPServer
}

$Path | ForEach {$Path += $($_.FullName)
$File = Get-ChildItem $Path | Where { $_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-1) }
If ($File -eq $null)
{ $SMTPBody = "`nLaatste 24H is er niets meer gestuurd bij klant:`n`n     $($_.FullName) $path"

Send-MailMessage @SMTPMessage -Body $SMTPBody
}
}
```

Comment: Write a script that checks the last modified time stamp of the folder. Send yourself an email when your condition is true.

Comment: I am noob in writing scripts. I need help with that.

Comment: then you are misinformed on what the intent of StackOverFlow is. We are not here to code for you or teach you how to code from scratch. The site was created to help others with existing code they are having problems with.

Comment: Have you ever bothered to read at least the [tour], or the article [ask]?

Comment: Sorry guys, i have now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on how much time you want to use and where the files are saved.
If it is a server, either Windows or Linux/Unix Windows PowerShell or PowerShell core on Linux/Unix could be used together with a scheduled task / cron job.

You could set the job to run a script every x hours.
Check the created or last edited date of each backup file and compare it to the current timestamp. If the files edit / create date is longer than your set limit, send an email, write a log or however you wish to handle it.